# Alternatives to "you can't shoot/fire a cannon from a canoe"?

Tags: idiom-requests

In YouTube videos and online articles about sports and sports training, I have come across the expression, "You can't fire a cannon from a canoe" (or "You can't shoot a cannon from a canoe"). It means that you need a stable foundation for many types of movements.

For examples, see

- Tom Kelso: [How To Shoot A Cannon Out Of A Canoe](https://breakingmuscle.com/learn/how-to-shoot-a-cannon-out-of-a-canoe):

  > Shoot a cannon out of a canoe and it will be a dud because the force of the cannon shot (the action) will not be countered by the weak opposing force of the canoe and water (opposite reaction.) Launching a cannon shot from solid ground will create a better result due to the greater opposing force supplied by the stable ground. (...) So the message for you athletes is to improve the strength of your lower body to optimize your launching ability regardless of your sport or event.
- [You Can Not Shoot a Cannon from a Canoe](http://fitgolf.com/you-can-not-shoot-a-cannon-from-a-canoe/) on fitgolf.com:

  > There is an old saying that you can not shoot a cannon from a canoe. The reason is that if you do so the cannon exerts a downward force when it is fired and blows a hole through the canoe and it sinks. However, this downward force is exactly what you want to create when you start the downswing in your golf swing. It is created by feeling that you are actually sitting down.
- Veronique Roberts: [Shooting a cannon from a canoe, Core Strength, Redefined](https://veroniqueroberts.com/2016/05/13/shooting-a-cannon-from-a-canoe-core-strength-redefined/):

  > An unstable spine is like shooting a cannon from a canoe. It wastes energy, which creates energy leaks. Those energy leaks can lead to overuse injuries over time.

I like the expression but I'm still curious to know whether there are other idioms with the same meaning.

Comment: Well they are wrong, of course.

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed, you can get off one or two rounds. http://www.keyshistory.org/TTK-Tea-Table-Key.html

Comment: @PhilSweet Well, that seems to *increase* the need for alternative expressions ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**[Don't] build on sand**

> Build on sand
>
> Use an unstable foundation, as in
>
> *If you buy nothing but high-risk stocks, your portfolio will be*
>   *built on sand.*
>
> This metaphor appears in
>   the New Testament, where Jesus likens those who do not heed his
>   sayings to a foolish man who builds his house on sand, which then is
>   washed away by rain, flood, and wind (Matthew 7:24–27). [ c. 1600 ]

[The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/build-on-sand)